# CMake unable to generate search path because of library conflict

Tags: cmake, conda, conflict

Dear Colleagues,
                I'm a newcommer to LINUX and am trying to use CMake to build a Geant4 example. After the following command

```
  $cmake ~/Geant4/geant4.10.05.p01-install/share/Geant4-10.5.1/examples/basic/B1/
```

I get this error message:

```
  Cannot generate a safe runtime search path for target exampleB1 because files in some directories 
  may conflict with libraries in implicit directories:
  runtime library [libexpat.so.1] in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu may be hidden by files in:
  /home/dakar/anaconda3/lib

  Some of these libraries may not be found correctly.
```

The warning is correct and when I run `$ make -j6` I get the error message

```
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so： undefined reference to 
    ‘uuid_generate@UUID_1.0’
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so： undefined reference 
    to‘uuid_unparse_lower@UUID_1.0’
```

This problem has been encountered before and some solutions are described in detail here:

https://github.com/pism/pism/issues/356

The page the URL links to say that for Conda 4.4+ this issue shouldn't occur. I'm using Conda 4.6.14 but the page adds that if does occur: you can set the `NOCONDA_PATH` variable in your `.bashrc` (or similar) just before you add conda to your path like so:

```
    export NOCONDA_PATH=$PATH
    export PATH=$HOME/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

I tried this and my `.bashrc` now reads:

```
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/home/dakar/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null$
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/dakar/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/dakar/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
#       \export NOCONDA_PATH=$PATH
        \export PATH="/home/dakar/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<

export CLHEP_DIR=/home/dakar/CLHEP/2.3.3.2/CLHEP-install/
export CLHEP_INCLUDE_DIR=${CLHEP_DIR}/include/
export CLHEP_LIBRARY=${CLHEP_DIR}/lib/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${CLHEP_LIBRARY}:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
export PATH=$CLHEP_DIR/bin/:$PATH

export TOPAS_G4_DATA_DIR=~/G4Data
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/topas/libexternal/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
#export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/anaconda3/lib/gcc/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
#CERN ROOT
#export ROOTSYS=/usr/local/root
#export PATH=$ROOTSYS/bin:$PATH
#export PYTHONDIR=$ROOTSYS
#export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ROOTSYS/lib:$PYTHONDIR/lib:$ROOTSYS/bindings/pyroot:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
#export PYTHONPATH=$ROOTSYS/lib:$PYTHONPATH:$ROOTSYS/bindings/pyroot
source ~/Geant4/geant4.10.05.p01-install/bin/geant4.sh
#source ~/Geant4/geant4.10.05.p01-install/share/Geant4-10.5.1/geant4make/geant4make.sh

export NOCONDA_PATH=$PATH
export PATH="/home/dakar/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

This still hasn't solved the problem. When I run `echo $PATH` I can still see conda directories:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/dakar/anaconda3/bin:/home/dakar/Geant4/geant4.10.05.p01-install/bin:/home/dakar/CLHEP/2.3.3.2/CLHEP-install//bin/:/home/dakar/anaconda3/bin:/home/dakar/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin:/home/dakar/bin:/home/dakar/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Does anybody have any further advice? Would uninstalling Conda itself be a solution.

Thanks for your time.
                       L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message suggests that you are missing libuuid in your linker invocation.

Try to add -luuid to your linker flags.

Does your build system use pkg-config? In this case you could edit `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/sm.pc` and add -luuid to the `Libs`-Section.

This looks like a bug in your Linux-Distro.

Comment: Thanks @arved for taking the time to reply. I think you are right: there is likely a bug in my Linux-Distro. I did not have the same problem when I built Geant4 on another computer. I think I will continue using the second installaion rather going back and fixing the first. But what about my original question: Would uninstalling Anaconda solve the problem？

Comment: It will remove the warning about libexpat. But it will not solve your error